# content type showing as link but not in "node_type" table

Tags: nodes, rules, database

In the development of a Drupal7 site, I have used various methods of creating profiles for customers of the site. One of the methods involved using a rule to create content for user who creates an account.

Unfortunately, this method did not work out, so the plan changed. At this point, the content type that was created by the rule cannot be removed and is showing up in the list of options for creating content, but is not in the node_type table in the MySQL database. I cannot seem to be able to remove this content type from showing up on such list.

The content type is not showing up under the content types administration interface, but it is showing under the add content list given to users who want to add content.

What methods can i take to manually remove a content type from the list of options given to a user in creating content?

Comment: Have you cleared your caches?

Comment: yes, clearing the cache did not remove the content-type from showing on the list of types of content to create. it is a dead-link at the top of the list, bypassing the order (alphabetically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the resolution on [drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/1047250)

One comment explains how to "reset" the content type from the navigation menu.

> This fixed the problem! What I did:

- Go to the navigation page, admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation
- find the link to the content type that is no longer there. It should be in the list under "add content".
- To the right there's buttons to edit and reset the link. You want to reset. This forces Drupal to reevaluate the link.
- It refreshes and poof! Gone from navigation, from add content page as well.

Comment: It's the right thing to do.